# How can I create unique 9 numbers(4 first digits will be year) then increment by 1? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have module called Add New Employee.One of my field is called Employee ID, in here I want to create a unique 9 digits number. The first 4 digits will be the current year and the rest will be 00001.

Example:

```
201700001
```

Then when I add another new employee it will increment by 1.

Example:

```
201700002
```

What If I want to put some plot twist, if it is reach to 9 it will look like this and so on.

Example:

```
201700010
```

Question: How can I increment the given format? Then if it is reach to 9 it will become 0 and the next number will be one? Like my third example above.

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form id="new-employee">
      <label>Employee ID</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" value="<?= increment_string(date("Y"), '0000');?>">
      <input class="form-control" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" disabled="" placeholder="<?= increment_string(date("Y"), '0000');?>">
<br>
</div>
```

Note: In my code it will only give you 201700001, then when I create new employe the employee is the same.

Comment: Hint: Don't try to increment the number after it's been formatted with dashes. Increment the raw number and *then* format it with dashes.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. But it should be only 201700001, without dashes

Comment: You're starting at 0 every time. You need to look up the last number that was used and then increment that.

Comment: why would you need to do that in PHP instead of in the database?

Comment: @Gordon Because I want it to display in my view before creating the new employee

Comment: yes, ok. but why do you wanna do that? does it serve any purpose?

Comment: The employee ID will be serve as your account to login :)

Comment: why not just do what everyone does and use a dun dun dun username based on their first and last name or something! if for any reason you need to get the date an employee was added just add that as a field to the database. don't mess with something tried and true. even if you do go with the method you propose you will always have to get the last employee id so you can increment it. and i think what @Gordon is getting at is that if it just serves as a id field then why display it back to the admin or whomever is creating the account? it is not like they can do anything to change it ;p

Comment: also take in to account the situation in which one admin is adding a user and the other is adding a user having loaded the page at the same time. both will be served with say `201700001` and when they go to submit to the database, one will succeed and the other will (hopefully) fail (if you designed in checks for this)... it's called a race condition. again, if you designed in checks you could always increment the counter before hitting the db, but that negates the view aspect as the id will change before the user sees it (otherwise you're redirecting back to the form which is bad ux).

Answer (score 0):

```
$next_number=substr($last_number, 4)      // the year
  . substr("0000"                         // pad out to at least 5 characters
      . (1+(int)substr($last_number, 4))  // increment the number
      , -5);                              // keep the last 5 characters
```

As a programming exercise this is trivial. But its the wrong way to fix the problem - the right way is to keep the year and number as seperate attributes in a database (for preference storing the last allocated number for each year seperately to simply generation of next)

Comment: I tried your code, and created a variable where it will get the current date. $current_year = date("Y");$next_number=substr($current_year, 4)   substr("0000"                         // pad out to at least 5 characters
                                  . (1+(int)substr($current_year, 4))  // increment the number
                                  , -5);  . The current date is missing.

Comment: The function above is for homomorphic values. Try `$last_number='201700001';` BTW your logic above has race condition errors.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be enough?

```
$num = 10;
$str = str_pad($num, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); //00010
$formatted = substr_replace($str, "-", -1, 0); //0001-0
```

Edit:

```
public function increment_string($year, $num) {
     $str = str_pad($num++, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); //00010
     $formatted = substr_replace($str, "-", -1, 0); //0001-0
     return "{$year}-{$formatted}"; //2017-0001-0
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and change it a bit.
$current_year = date("Y"); $str = str_pad($current_year, 9, 0);
$employee = increment_string($str,'1');
How it will become 201700002?

Comment: Sir, I want it to display first in my view before I save it to my table. Imagine im in the new-employee view. In my center of my screen there will be a field Employee ID - 201700001. Then when I create new Employee it will should be now 201700002

Comment: Suppose that the latest employee you have is 20170009, perform `(int) substr('20170009', 4)` and you'll get `9`, then to increment it to the next sequence call the method I provided you.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the form retrieve the last created ID, increment by 1, pass the result to the client browser. The problem with this is if two people create a new student at the same time. Recommendation: create the ID AFTER the student data is submitted. What is the point in having the ID availalbe befopre the data is saved?